# target_blank opening the url in same tab and a new empty tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

The code below is opening the url in the same page(tab) and also creates a new empty tab.I want to open the      url in another tab or window and my page remains same without changing.

```
<a  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Apply Now', 'Click', 'Stage 1']);location.href='http://www.testlink.com/course/test11'" target="_blank">Apply now</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<a  href="#" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Apply Now', 'Click', 'Stage 1']);window.open('http://www.testlink.com/course/test11', '_blank')">Apply now</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you can't put the link in the 'href' attribute? `target="_blank"` will force it to open in a new window/tab.

```
<a href="http://www.testlink.com/course/test11" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Apply Now', 'Click', 'Stage 1']);" target="_blank">Apply now</a>
```

Comment: The above also working fine.For some reason we have used href="javascript:void",instead of putting link directly in href attribute.

Comment: The advantage of using the href attribute is that users with Javascript disabled can also visit the link. Also, search engines will be able to follow the link, which will help them to index your site.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't suggest that myself. :-D This is better than using `window.open`.